# How can I stream a NumPy array into a stream?

Tags: python, numpy, pyaudio

I am trying to do a realtime player/recorder looper. I´m just starting and dealing win PyAudio.

At the moment, I am able to create a stream and store it in to a numpy array, but I am not able to send it back to the pyaudio stream when I want.

I want to use arrays because I prefer to store everything in the memory until I want to save it as wave files.

Note that I try to play it with Matth´s python-sounddevice, but I'm also not able to play it. I can't find the way to achieve this.

Here´s my current code:

```
import sys
import pyaudio
import numpy as np
import sounddevice as sd

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
datos_numpy=np.array([])
CHUNK=64
CHANNELS=2
FORMAT=pyaudio.paFloat32
RATE=44100

is_recording=False
is_playing=False

def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    global datos_numpy, is_playing, is_recording
    if is_recording==True:
        if in_data:
            print 'recording'
            temp_data=np.fromstring(in_data, dtype=np.float32)
            datos_numpy = np.append(datos_numpy,temp_data)
        else:
            print('no input')

        return in_data, pyaudio.paContinue

    elif is_playing==True:
            print 'playing'
            #out_data= ???? HERE IS MY PROBLEM
            #return out_data, pyaudio.paContinue   
    else:
        return in_data, pyaudio.paContinue


stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                output=True,
                input=True,
                input_device_index=6,
                output_device_index=14,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK,
                stream_callback=callback)

def record():
    global is_playing, is_recording
    is_recording=True
    is_playing=False


def play():
    global is_playing, is_recording, datos_numpy
    is_recording=False
    is_playing=True
    sd.play(datos_numpy, 44100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are getting the numpy array by `fromstring` method, you may be able toget the string buffer back by `numpy.tostring()` method.

Alternatively, instead of converting it to a numpy array, you can simply pickle the string buffer to hard disk. Then you do not have to worry about how to get the working buffer back.